Problematic destructor in a circularly linked sparse matrix program
This is not a homework problem but for self-study.
I am writing a program that reads in user input and transforms it into a sparse matrix (operator>>), adds two sparse matrices (operator+), and prints a sparse matrix (operator<<) represented by circular linked lists.
With the destructor, the operator<< function handles two input matrices correctly but gives a segmentation fault for the sum of two sparse matrices a and b.
The absence of destructor ~Matrix(), however, resolves the segmentation fault caused by the operator<< function.
Does this mean that I should rewrite the ~Matrix() destructor, or change the function definition of operator<< and/or operator+? I already have a copy constructor, a default constructor, and a destructor.
1. main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "SparseMatrix.h"

int main() {
    Matrix matrixFirst, matrixSecond;
    Matrix matrixSum;
    
    std::cout<<"Please enter number of rows, number of columns, and number of entries."<<std::endl;
    std::cin >> matrixFirst;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Printing sparse matrix..." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Row, Column, Value" << std::endl;
    std::cout << matrixFirst << std::endl;
    
    std::cout<<"Please enter number of rows, number of columns, and number of entries."<<std::endl;
    std::cin >> matrixSecond;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Printing sparse matrix..." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Row, Column, Value" << std::endl;
    std::cout << matrixSecond << std::endl;
    
    matrixSum = matrixFirst + matrixSecond;
    std::cout << "Sum: " << matrixSum << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}

2. SparseMatrix.h
#ifndef SPARSEMATRIX_H
#define SPARSEMATRIX_H

#include <iostream> // Include necessary header

enum Boolean { FALSE, TRUE };
struct Triple { int row, col, value; };

class Matrix;
class MatrixNode {
    friend class Matrix;
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Matrix& matrix);
    
    //2024 July 27: I need to change this function.
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Matrix& matrix);
    
    friend Matrix operator+(const Matrix& a, const Matrix& b); 
    
  private:
    MatrixNode *down, *right;
    Boolean head;
    union {
        MatrixNode* next;
        Triple triple;
    };
    MatrixNode(Boolean b, Triple* t); //constructor
};

typedef MatrixNode* MatrixNodePtr;
extern MatrixNodePtr av; // Extern to declare the global variable

class Matrix {
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Matrix& matrix);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Matrix& matrix);
    friend Matrix operator+(const Matrix& a, const Matrix& b);
  public:
    Matrix(); //Constructor
    Matrix(const Matrix& other); //Copy constructor
    ~Matrix(); //Destructor
  private:
    MatrixNode *headNode;
};

#endif

3. SparseMatrix.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "SparseMatrix.h"

MatrixNodePtr av = nullptr; // Define the global variable

MatrixNode::MatrixNode(Boolean b, Triple* t) {
    head = b;
    if (b) {
        right = next = this;
    } else {
        triple = *t;
    }
}

//Reads in a matrix and sets up its linked representation.
//An auxiliary array head[] is used.
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Matrix& matrix) {
    Triple s; int p;
    is >> s.row >> s.col >> s.value;
    if (s.row > s.col) p = s.row;
    else p = s.col;
    //Sets up headNode for list of head nodes.
    matrix.headNode = new MatrixNode(FALSE, &s);
    if (p == 0) {
        matrix.headNode->right = matrix.headNode;
        return is;
    }
    std::cout << "Please specify row, column, and value." << std::endl;
    //At least one row or column
    MatrixNodePtr *head = new MatrixNodePtr[p]; //initialize head nodes
    for (int i = 0; i < p; i++) 
        head[i] = new MatrixNode(TRUE, nullptr);
    int CurrentRow = 0; MatrixNode *last = head[0]; //last node in the current row
    for (int i = 0; i < s.value; i++) {
        std::cout << "Row, Column, Value: ";
        Triple t;
        is >> t.row >> t.col >> t.value;
        if (t.row > CurrentRow) {
            last->right = head[CurrentRow];
            CurrentRow = t.row;
            last = head[CurrentRow];
        } //end if
        last = last->right = new MatrixNode(FALSE, &t); //link new node into row list
        head[t.col]->next = head[t.col]->next->down = last; //link into column list
    } //end of for
    
    last->right = head[CurrentRow]; //close last row
    for (int i = 0; i < s.col; i++) head[i]->next->down = head[i]; //close all column lists
    //link the head nodes together
    for (int i = 0; i < p - 1; i++) head[i]->next = head[i + 1];
    head[p - 1]->next = matrix.headNode;
    matrix.headNode->right = head[0];
    delete[] head;
    return is;
} //end of overloaded operator function


std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, Matrix &m) {
    MatrixNode *headNode = m.headNode->right;
    while (headNode != m.headNode) {
        //This line causes a segmentation fault.
        for (MatrixNode *cur = headNode->right; cur != headNode; cur = cur->right)
            os << "(" << cur->triple.row << ", " << cur->triple.col << ", " << cur->triple.value << ")" << std::endl;
        headNode = headNode->next;
    }
    return os;
}

Matrix operator+(const Matrix& a, const Matrix& b) {
    if (a.headNode->triple.row != b.headNode->triple.row || 
        a.headNode->triple.col != b.headNode->triple.col) {
        throw std::invalid_argument("Matrix dimensions do not match");
    }

    Matrix result;
    result.headNode = new MatrixNode(FALSE, &a.headNode->triple);
    int rows = result.headNode->triple.row;
    int cols = result.headNode->triple.col;

    // Create head nodes for rows
    MatrixNodePtr* rowHeads = new MatrixNodePtr[rows];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        rowHeads[i] = new MatrixNode(TRUE, nullptr);
        rowHeads[i]->right = rowHeads[i];  // Initialize right pointer
    }

    MatrixNodePtr aRowHead = a.headNode->right;
    MatrixNodePtr bRowHead = b.headNode->right;

    while (aRowHead != a.headNode && bRowHead != b.headNode) {
        MatrixNodePtr aPtr = aRowHead->right;
        MatrixNodePtr bPtr = bRowHead->right;

        while (aPtr != aRowHead || bPtr != bRowHead) {
            Triple t;
            if (aPtr == aRowHead || (bPtr != bRowHead && 
                (bPtr->triple.row < aPtr->triple.row || 
                (bPtr->triple.row == aPtr->triple.row && bPtr->triple.col < aPtr->triple.col)))) {
                t = bPtr->triple;
                bPtr = bPtr->right;
            } else if (bPtr == bRowHead || aPtr->triple.row < bPtr->triple.row || 
                       (aPtr->triple.row == bPtr->triple.row && aPtr->triple.col < bPtr->triple.col)) {
                t = aPtr->triple;
                aPtr = aPtr->right;
            } else {
                t = aPtr->triple;
                t.value += bPtr->triple.value;
                aPtr = aPtr->right;
                bPtr = bPtr->right;
            }

            std::cout << "Processing triple: (" << t.row << ", " << t.col << ", " << t.value << ")" << std::endl;

            if (t.value != 0) {
                MatrixNodePtr newNode = new MatrixNode(FALSE, &t);
                MatrixNodePtr rowPrev = rowHeads[t.row];
                while (rowPrev->right != rowHeads[t.row] && rowPrev->right->triple.col < t.col) {
                    rowPrev = rowPrev->right;
                }
                newNode->right = rowPrev->right;
                rowPrev->right = newNode;
            }
        }
        
        aRowHead = aRowHead->next;
        bRowHead = bRowHead->next;
    }

    // Process any remaining rows in a
    while (aRowHead != a.headNode) {
        MatrixNodePtr aPtr = aRowHead->right;
        while (aPtr != aRowHead) {
            Triple t = aPtr->triple;
            if (t.value != 0) {
                MatrixNodePtr newNode = new MatrixNode(FALSE, &t);
                MatrixNodePtr rowPrev = rowHeads[t.row];
                while (rowPrev->right != rowHeads[t.row] && rowPrev->right->triple.col < t.col) {
                    rowPrev = rowPrev->right;
                }
                newNode->right = rowPrev->right;
                rowPrev->right = newNode;
            }
            aPtr = aPtr->right;
        }
        aRowHead = aRowHead->next;
    }

    // Process any remaining rows in b
    while (bRowHead != b.headNode) {
        MatrixNodePtr bPtr = bRowHead->right;
        while (bPtr != bRowHead) {
            Triple t = bPtr->triple;
            if (t.value != 0) {
                MatrixNodePtr newNode = new MatrixNode(FALSE, &t);
                MatrixNodePtr rowPrev = rowHeads[t.row];
                while (rowPrev->right != rowHeads[t.row] && rowPrev->right->triple.col < t.col) {
                    rowPrev = rowPrev->right;
                }
                newNode->right = rowPrev->right;
                rowPrev->right = newNode;
            }
            bPtr = bPtr->right;
        }
        bRowHead = bRowHead->next;
    }

    // Link row heads
    for (int i = 0; i < rows - 1; i++) {
        rowHeads[i]->next = rowHeads[i + 1];
    }
    rowHeads[rows - 1]->next = result.headNode;
    result.headNode->right = rowHeads[0];

    // Count non-zero elements
    int valueCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (MatrixNodePtr p = rowHeads[i]->right; p != rowHeads[i]; p = p->right) {
            valueCount++;
        }
    }
    result.headNode->triple.value = valueCount;

    delete[] rowHeads;
    return result;
} 

Matrix::Matrix() : headNode(nullptr) {};

Matrix::Matrix(const Matrix& other) : headNode(nullptr) {
    if (other.headNode) {
        Triple headTriple = other.headNode->triple;
        headNode = new MatrixNode(FALSE, &headTriple);
        int rows = headTriple.row;
        int cols = headTriple.col;

        // Create head nodes for rows
        MatrixNodePtr* rowHeads = new MatrixNodePtr[rows];
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            rowHeads[i] = new MatrixNode(TRUE, nullptr);
            rowHeads[i]->right = rowHeads[i];  // Initialize right pointer
        }

        MatrixNodePtr otherRowHead = other.headNode->right;

        while (otherRowHead != other.headNode) {
            MatrixNodePtr otherCurrent = otherRowHead->right;
            while (otherCurrent != otherRowHead) {
                Triple t = otherCurrent->triple;
                MatrixNodePtr newNode = new MatrixNode(FALSE, &t);
                MatrixNodePtr rowPrev = rowHeads[t.row];
                while (rowPrev->right != rowHeads[t.row] && rowPrev->right->triple.col < t.col) {
                    rowPrev = rowPrev->right;
                }
                newNode->right = rowPrev->right;
                rowPrev->right = newNode;

                // Link into column list
                rowHeads[t.col]->next = rowHeads[t.col]->next->down = newNode;

                otherCurrent = otherCurrent->right;
            }
            otherRowHead = otherRowHead->next;
        }

        // Link row heads
        for (int i = 0; i < rows - 1; i++) {
            rowHeads[i]->next = rowHeads[i + 1];
        }
        rowHeads[rows - 1]->next = headNode;
        headNode->right = rowHeads[0];

        delete[] rowHeads;
    }
}

/**Returns all nodes to the av (available space) list. This list is a chain
 * linked via the right field. av is a global variable of type MatrixNode*
 * and points to its first node.
 */ 
Matrix::~Matrix() {
    if (!headNode) return; //no node to dispose
    MatrixNode *x = headNode->right;
    MatrixNode *y;
    headNode->right = av;
    av = headNode; //return headNode
    while (x != headNode) {
        y = x->right;
        x->right = av;
        av = y;
        x = x->next;
    }
    headNode = nullptr;
}

Sample Input/Output without destructor
Please enter number of rows, number of columns, and number of entries.
1 1 1
Please specify row, column, and value.
Row, Column, Value: 0 0 3

Printing sparse matrix...
Row, Column, Value
(0, 0, 3)

Please enter number of rows, number of columns, and number of entries.
1 1 1
Please specify row, column, and value.
Row, Column, Value: 0 0 2

Printing sparse matrix...
Row, Column, Value
(0, 0, 2)

Processing triple: (0, 0, 5)
Sum: (0, 0, 5)


If a class has a destructor and neither copy-constructor or copy-operator, this class is likely poorly designed and has errors.

Self study is fine, and this code is fine too. But you need a good source to be learning from since there are large gaps in your knowledge. I suggest https://learncpp.com

The absence of destructor ~Matrix(), however, resolves the segmentation fault caused by the operator<< function. -- It really didn't resolve anything.  That's like saying "my car now starts up after I removed the brakes".  The problem isn't that there is a destructor -- the problem is that the destructor exposed the other issues with your code, namely that your classes are not safely-copyable.

int main() { Matrix m; std::cin >> m; Matrix m2; m = m2; } -- That program has a double-free error, all due to a missing user-defined assignment operator.

Your advice of adding a operator= function helped me resolve the error. Thank you so much.

@john Thank you for the link. Moving forward, I will definitely use that resource.
